# How do I hard code and sum results for a specific result in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below XML and XSL. I'd like to produce a specific output result for one specific ID, but have the rest of the data process as normal. I'm not sure of syntax to accomplish this, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

So something like this:
If ID = 12345 then
Hard code the Contribution_desc to be 'Payroll Deduction'
and
Sum both Report_Entry nodes into one output for contribution_Amount.
Everyone else gets an output row per Report_Entry

So in ouput for 12345,
Contribution_desc = Payroll Deduction and
contribution_Amount = 50.
He would only have one output

56789 will still have two rows of output

XML input

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ContributionData">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker><wd:ID>12345</wd:ID></wd:Worker>     
        <wd:Deduction_Description>Employer Contribution</wd:Deduction_Description>
        <wd:Current_Period_Result>25</wd:Current_Period_Result>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker><wd:ID>12345</wd:ID></wd:Worker> 
        <wd:Deduction_Description>Payroll Deduction</wd:Deduction_Description>
        <wd:Current_Period_Result>25</wd:Current_Period_Result>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker><wd:ID>56789</wd:ID></wd:Worker>
        <wd:Deduction_Description>Employer Contribution</wd:Deduction_Description>
        <wd:Current_Period_Result>41.66</wd:Current_Period_Result>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Worker><wd:ID>56789</wd:ID></wd:Worker>
        <wd:Deduction_Description>Payroll Deduction</wd:Deduction_Description>
        <wd:Current_Period_Result>48.33</wd:Current_Period_Result>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

XSL sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:out="http://www.workday.com/integration/output" 
    xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ContributionData">
    
        
    <!--
    If ID = 12345 
    Hard code the Contribution_desc to be 'Payroll Deduction' 
    and
    Sum both Report_Entry nodes into one output for contribution_Amount
    Everyone else gets an output row per Report_Entry
    
    So in ouput for 12345
    Contribution_desc = Payroll Deduction
    contribution_Amount = 50
    And he would only have one output 
    
    56789 will still have two rows of output
    -->
        
    <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data">        
        <File xtt:separator="&#xd;&#xa;">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:Worker/wd:ID">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="wd:Deduction_Description">
                <CT xtt:separator="|">
                    <ID><xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker/wd:ID"/></ID>
                    <Contribution_desc><xsl:value-of select="wd:Deduction_Description"/></Contribution_desc>
                    <contribution_Amount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()//wd:Current_Period_Result),'#0.00')"/></contribution_Amount>
                </CT>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>            
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is current output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<File xmlns:out="http://www.workday.com/integration/output" xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv"
    xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ContributionData"
    xtt:separator="&#xD;&#xA;">
    <CT xtt:separator="|">
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Contribution_desc>Employer Contribution</Contribution_desc>
        <contribution_Amount>25.00</contribution_Amount>
    </CT>
    <CT xtt:separator="|">
        <ID>12345</ID>
        <Contribution_desc>Payroll Deduction</Contribution_desc>
        <contribution_Amount>25.00</contribution_Amount>
    </CT>
    <CT xtt:separator="|">
        <ID>56789</ID>
        <Contribution_desc>Employer Contribution</Contribution_desc>
        <contribution_Amount>41.66</contribution_Amount>
    </CT>
    <CT xtt:separator="|">
        <ID>56789</ID>
        <Contribution_desc>Payroll Deduction</Contribution_desc>
        <contribution_Amount>48.33</contribution_Amount>
    </CT>
</File>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you just want to check your outer grouping key e.g.

```
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry" group-by="wd:Worker/wd:ID">
          <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = 12345">
            <CT xtt:separator="|">
                <ID><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></ID>
                <Contribution_desc>Payroll Deduction</Contribution_desc>
                <contribution_Amount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()//wd:Current_Period_Result),'#0.00')"/></contribution_Amount>
            </CT>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="wd:Deduction_Description">
            <CT xtt:separator="|">
                <ID><xsl:value-of select="wd:Worker/wd:ID"/></ID>
                <Contribution_desc><xsl:value-of select="wd:Deduction_Description"/></Contribution_desc>
                <contribution_Amount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()//wd:Current_Period_Result),'#0.00')"/></contribution_Amount>
            </CT>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
           </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: Brilliant, that was exactly it!  How do I know where to add the 'choose'?  I wasn't sure if it went before or after the CT, before or after the Report Entry group, or before/after the group entry.